# There is an error while I install an npm package google-maps-react

Tags: npm, google-maps-react

[image]

Can someone explain How to solve this error?
I have seen some similar queries in stack overflow and elsewhere, but couldnt solve the issue

Comment: Which exactly OS are You using?

Comment: @MarioG8 I am using windows.... with hyper terminal which uses linux commands

Comment: Have You tried to type  npm install google-map-react ? ;-)

Comment: isn't it same as npm i google-maps-react
Which is giving the error as in the photo i shared?

Comment: Just try it ;-)

Comment: Did that .. didnt work

Comment: okay that's one more idea, if your terminal uses linux commands try this:  "sudo  npm i google-map-react"

Comment: not working ... It has to do something with clearing cache and stuff Which I am not really sure of how

Comment: "npm cache clean"  make sure you are in the project folder if you enter these commands... and one more idea use regular windows console instead of hyper terminal... Calm down and patience  we will seek and destroy the issue ;_-) update node and npm as well ...

Comment: actually npm cache clean is giving the same kind of error as well!!.... The reason for using hyper terminal is to get used with the linux commands.... It doesnt break very often though

Comment: One last tip, restart your machine, update node and npm and try use this commands in  cmd  from win, remember you have to be in root project directory .